# View background won't change after clicking it and using ternary

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist

So I am displaying 5 stars. They are all gray on default when they are not selected. When I click on the star, I want the background color to change of the View but it is not changing after clicking it. Also, if I click star 3, I want the stars before star 3 to also change the background color. But nothing is working.

I used console.log to view the changed list when handleStarClicked runs and it saves the changes but not sure what is going on. Would really appreciate some help, please

```js
const stars = [{ id: 0, selected: false }, { id: 1, selected: false }, { id: 2, selected: false }, { id: 3, selected: false }, { id: 4, selected: false }];

const [holdStars, setHoldStars] = useState(stars);

const handleStarClicked = (id) => {
  for (let i = 0 ; i < holdStars.length; i++) {
    if (i <= id) {
      holdStars[i].selected = true;
    } else {
      holdStars[i].selected = false;
    }
  }
  setHoldStars(holdStars);
}

return (
    <FlatList
      data={holdStars}
      horizontal
      scrollEnabled={false}
      renderItem={({ item }) => 
      <Pressable onPress={() => handleStarClicked(item.id)} className="ml-1 p-1 rounded-xl items-center justify-center" style={{ backgroundColor: item.selected ? "#6ECCAF" : "#CCCCCC" }}>
        <Icon name="star" type="AntDesign" size={32} color="white" />
      </Pressable>
    }
    />
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are modifying the holdStars array directly in the handleStarClicked function and that is causing the issue.
Try this :

```
const handleStarClicked = (id) => {
  const newHoldStars = [...holdStars]; // create a new copy of the holdStars array
  for (let i = 0 ; i < newHoldStars.length; i++) {
    if (i <= id) {
      newHoldStars[i].selected = true;
    } else {
      newHoldStars[i].selected = false;
    }
  }
  setHoldStars(newHoldStars);
}
```

Comment: i see. it is working now. thank you for your help. I tried something similar before creating a temp variable like tempHoldStars = holdStars but that wasn't working either. So I was missing [...holdStars]. What is the rule/definition of using [...variable]